# Перестала работать клавиша "DELETE" в Visual Studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Перестала работать клавиша del в VS Code.
Конкретнее - в сайдбаре, где с её помощью удалял ненужные файлы. Теперь же вместо удаления, открывается что-то вроде фильтра поиска, где при каждом нажатии добавляется delete (см. скрин).

Буду благодарен за совет
п.с. Убунту 18.04

[[image: Проблема[1]]

---

Всё решилось с обновлением vs Code. Спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в настройках(File-Preferences-Keyboard Shortcuts) не переназначина ли клавиша. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Увы, не переназначено. Не могу понять, просто среди кодинга возникла проблема, вроде даже никаких шорткатов не юзал